# How can I create a schema alias in DB2 on System z?

Tags: schema, odbc, db2, alias, mainframe

Part of a reporting toolkit we use for our development is configured to always use the same schema (say `XYZZY`).

However, certain customers have stored their data in a different schema `PLUGH`. Is there any way within DB2/z to alias the entire *schema* `XYZZY` to refer to the objects in schema `PLUGH`?

The reporting toolkit runs on top of ODBC using the DB2 Connect Enterprise Edition or Personal Edition 9.1 drivers.

I know I can set up individual aliases for tables and views but we have many *hundreds* of these database objects and it will be a serious pain to do the lot. It would be far easier to simply have DB2 auto-magically translate the whole schema.

Keep in mind we're not looking for being able to run with multiple schemas, we just want a way to redirect all requests for database objects to a single, differently named, schema.

Of course, if there's a way to get multiple schemas on a per-connection basis, that would be good as well. But I'm not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that by DB/2 *schema* you mean the qualifying name in some two part object name. For 
example, if a two
part table name is: `PLUGH.SOME_TABLE_NAME`. You want to do define `XYZZY` as an
alias name for `PLUGH` so the reporting program can refer to the table as `XYZZY.SOME_TABLE_NAME`.

I don't know how to directly do that (schema names don't take on aliases as far as I am aware). 
The objection you have to defining individual alias names
using something like:

```
CREATE ALIAS XYZZY.SOME_TABLE_NAME FOR PLUGH.SOME_TABLE_NAME
```

is that there are hundreds of them to do making it a real pain. Have you thought about
using a `SELECT` against the DB/2 catalogue to generate `CREATE ALIAS` statements for
each of the objects you need to refer to? Something like:

```
SELECT 'CREATE ALIAS XYZZY.' || NAME || ' FOR PLUGH.' || NAME
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE CREATOR = 'PLUGH'
```

Capture the output into a file then execute it.  Might be hundreds of commands,
but at least you didn't have to write them.